# Georgia visa for a Pakistan citizen

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, georgia-country

I am a Pakistani passport holder and planning to visit Georgia (the country) for my holidays. As there is no embassy of Georgia in Pakistan, I am finding it pretty difficult to get the basic information about visa requirements.

What do I need to visit Georgia?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE! You don't need a signature here, since it's already included in the lower-right hand corner.

Comment: I have also found inconsistent information online. This is probably because the requirements have changed recently, so many sites probably show outdated information.  In any event, you'll certainly want to have a look at https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/.

Answer (score 7):

I visited Georgia last year on valid UK 5 years visa on Pakistani passport without any Georgian visa, also [the immigration Georgia sent me a link which was really helpful](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=26&lang=Eng).

If you have a valid visa/residence permit from UK,USA,canada,new Zealand, Australia, any EU country or residence permit in Saudi Arabia,Oman,Qatar,Bahrain,Kuwait,Uae you may enter Georgia without a visa for 90 days.

However if you do not meet the above requirement, you will need a Georgia visa on Pakistani passport and Embassy of Georgia in Tehran can entertain your visa application. Moreover a invitation from Georgia is a must for Pakistani passport.

Here you can find all your answer from [this website](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/en/visaInformation).